# Extending circuit from dead-end 3-way switch

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

I have a dead end 3-way switch in a 2-gang box. The switch is fed with a 14/4 cable using black as common, red and blue travellers, and white as a capped neutral per code. I would like to add a standard 2-way switch to this box with 14/2 running to a fixture. I would do this by pigtailing the black/common and white/neutral of the 14/4.

Any issue with this?

Comment: the answer to your question is `yes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow.  You actually have /4.

The answer is it can work, but you may need to flip it.   That is to say, right now, the black wire may be switched-hot going to the lamp, so the wires are

> switched-hot traveler traveler neutral.

If so, you will need to rearrange other parts of the circuit so the other 3-way is the one with switched-hot and the wires that come here are

> always-hot traveler traveler neutral.

Then you can simply tap always-hot and neutral.

Tell whoever fit the /4, *well done*.   Normally this question answers with a "nope, unless you like smart switches".

Comment: Great. The layout is always-hot, traveler, traveler, neutral, so I should be all set. Thank you for the confirmation!